# MCP4131 with 8 - bit

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, digital-potentiometer, bit-rate

I am using MCP4131 with 7 - bit ( 0 - 127 ). Datasheet said that, it can work bit 7 and 8 bit and i definetly need to use it with 8 bit ( 0 - 255 ). Here is my code below;

```
#include <SPI.h>
byte address = 0x00;
int CS= 10;
void setup()
{
pinMode (CS, OUTPUT);
SPI.begin();

}
void loop()
{
digitalPotWrite(50);
}

int digitalPotWrite(int value)
{
digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
SPI.transfer(address);
SPI.transfer(value);
digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}
```

This is 7 bit code, to make it 8 bit, What should i change in the code ? Or what i need to do ?

Thank You
Best Regards

Comment: What does the datasheet tell you about its protocol, specifically?

Comment: <pedantic>7-bit is 0-127 and 8-bit is 0-255</pedantic>

Comment: @Wossname SPI Communication

Comment: @RogerRowland, this specific device actually does have 257 steps in it's 8bit mode.  0-255 and MAX.  Weird.  It's because there are 256 resistors internally, which gives 256+1 taps including both ends.  I've used this chip before and it's pretty awesome actually.

Comment: @FiratDagkiran, you need to read the datasheet in detail.  You need to research the problem before anyone will help you.

Comment: @Wossname oh ... interesting. Also, the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22060b.pdf) on page 85 defines which devices are 7-bit and which are 8-bit.

Comment: Have you read the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22060b.pdf)? The 8-bit parts are different from the 7-bit parts (different part numbers).

Answer (score 1):

From page 85 of [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22060b.pdf):

[image: datasheet]

You can see that the 7-bit and 8-bit options are different devices. So MCP4131 is 7-bit only. It seems you need MCP4151.

Answer (score -1):

This depends a lot on what is written in the datasheet on how to use it with the 8-bit feature. However, from your code it looks like you are storing the value in an integer and then writing that. Changing from `int` to `unsigned int` should work in this scenario but still a lot depends on what is written in the datasheet. It would be better if you clearly specify what is written in the datasheet regarding the use of 8-bit and 7-bit feature.